# How to overlay a <div> object and a raster Image

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to overlay some objects from up to down by this layer order:

1. Info window
2. PNG Image
3. Google Maps

I did overlay the 2nd and 3rd layer. However, I couldn't display `Info Window` upon it.

I debugged the modified code. It happened when I add the `autocomplete` variable, the overlay PNG image couldn't be displayed.

(The `autocomplete` variable was marked as a comment by me in the current code snippet below)

Do you have any idea, please? Thanks before

My 2nd layer image to be overlay is:
[image: Overlay PNG Image]

My code is:

```js
// This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
// a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

// Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
// of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
// it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
// google.maps.event.addDomListener().
// Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
// parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: -7.782886,
      lng: 110.367037
    },
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.9161700000000002, 110.1243099999999941),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.3161699999999996, 110.7243100000000027));

  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  var srcImage = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR3Rz.png';

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Variable untuk Location Seach Bar

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  // Variable untuk kotak keterangan lokasi

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  /*
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
 
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
   infowindow.close();
   var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   
   if (!place.geometry) {
    return;
   }

   if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport); 
   } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);
   }

   // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
   marker.setPlace({
    placeId: place.place_id,
    location: place.geometry.location
   });
   
   marker.setVisible(true);

   infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
   //infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;//Script penampil Place ID tidak perlu dijalankan
   infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = place.formatted_address;
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  */

  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}

/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
* element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.controls {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

.controls:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Thank you for looking around to this code</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
  <!-- Menampilkan Pigura Frame Google Maps API -->

  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
  <!-- Menampilkan Location Search Bar -->

  <div id="infowindow-content">
    <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
    <span id="place-id"></span><br>
    <span id="place-address"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- Menampilkan kotak keterangan lokasi -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
  </script>
  <!-- Java script for displaying Google Maps API-->
  <!-- The script was adopted from Google Developer (2018) -->
  <!-- You need Google Maps API Key to display the map on your web -->

  <!-- Code References
 SitePoint, HTML Template
  https://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/
  accessed on 12 January 2018
 HTML5 Doctor, CSS Reset
  http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/
  accessed on 11 January 2018
 Google Developers, Adding a Google Maps API
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map
  accessed on 11 January 2018
 Google Developers, Google Maps API PlaceID Finder
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map
  accessed on 15 January 2018
 -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Attention:** A web programmer needs to be aware with 'javascript console' inside the web browser. It will show you any error related to your script, if any. How to open the 'javascript console' for any browser, you can read it here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337

Comment: **Moreover:** in case you merge your javascript inside your HTML (single file), do not call your search script after your `overlay` and `initmap` scripts. I guess this problem is related to the script execution ques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get an error with the posted code: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function`.  Remove the callback parameter from the API include, change:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

To:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY&libraries=places">
</script>
```

**working code snippet:**

```js
// This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
// a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

// Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
// of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
// it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
// google.maps.event.addDomListener().
// Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
// parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: -7.782886,
      lng: 110.367037
    },
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.9161700000000002, 110.1243099999999941),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.3161699999999996, 110.7243100000000027));

  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  var srcImage = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR3Rz.png';

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Variable untuk Location Seach Bar

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  // Variable untuk kotak keterangan lokasi

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });


  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
    marker.setPlace({
      placeId: place.place_id,
      location: place.geometry.location
    });

    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    //infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;//Script penampil Place ID tidak perlu dijalankan
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = place.formatted_address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });


  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}

/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
* element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.controls {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

.controls:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Thank you for looking around to this code</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
  <!-- Menampilkan Pigura Frame Google Maps API -->

  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
  <!-- Menampilkan Location Search Bar -->

  <div id="infowindow-content">
    <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
    <span id="place-id"></span><br>
    <span id="place-address"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- Menampilkan kotak keterangan lokasi -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
  </script>
  <!-- Java script for displaying Google Maps API-->
  <!-- The script was adopted from Google Developer (2018) -->
  <!-- You need Google Maps API Key to display the map on your web -->

  <!-- Code References
    SitePoint, HTML Template
        https://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/
        accessed on 12 January 2018
    HTML5 Doctor, CSS Reset
        http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/
        accessed on 11 January 2018
    Google Developers, Adding a Google Maps API
        https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map
        accessed on 11 January 2018
    Google Developers, Google Maps API PlaceID Finder
        https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map
        accessed on 15 January 2018
    -->

</body>

</html>
```